# Why i don't have allProjects block in android/build.gradle file (React Native CLI Project)

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, react-native-cli

I am trying to intagrate a SDK to my React Native app.With respect to integration guide i need to add
maven { url 'http://repo.sapmple.com:8081/sapmple/sapmple' } in to my build.gradle file  also i need to be sure to add it to the “allprojects” block, above other maven repositories. But my build.gradle file look likes this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

Where should I add this maven code line ?

I have tried to add it into the repositories{} but i faced with problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can add maven code line to **settings.gradle** file as below,

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ı have tryed it but i have a error when i try to add SDK to my app.JS error: Could not find a declaration file for module '@xx-xx/react-native-xxx'. 'c:/Users/xxx/xxxx/node_modules/@xx-xxx/react-native-xxxx/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/xx-inside__react-native-xxx` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@xx-xxx/react-native-xxx';`ts(7016)